# Count posts per post-type for last month/week

Tags: php

I would like to display some stats on my website. For multiple post types I would like something like this:
`XXX Reviews (XX)`

1. where the first `XXX` is the total amount which I can get by using `wp_count_posts('reviews')`
2. where `Reviews` is the name of the posttype
3. where `(XX)` show how many reviews were added last month  or week (still need to decide on that but idea is the same)

I'm only missing point 3, how do I do this most efficient, I know I can use `get_posts()` and use dynamic vars to pull the data but I think is pretty resourceful right?

I need to do this for 4 post types on my home page, in the future, more might be added.

Comment: What about running a wp_query for reviews and limit the query for the date time required?

Comment: Isn't a wp_query pretty heavy to run as well? I think get_posts would even be faster.

Comment: `get_posts` is your answer. Add `'fields' => 'ids'` to the `get_posts` arguments, this way you get only the post ID's. This way you cut up to 99.9% on db queries and time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Besides [this suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194060/count-posts-per-post-type-for-last-month-week#comment283230_194060), here is a simple `SQL` query adapted from the core `wp_get_archives` function:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, 
    MONTH(post_date) AS `month`, 
    count(ID) as posts 
FROM 
    wp_posts 
WHERE 
    post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) 
ORDER BY 
    post_date DESC
```

This would provide with a structure like this:

```
+------+-------+-------+
| year | month | posts |
+------+-------+-------+
| 2015 |     5 |     1 |
| 2015 |     4 |     1 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

You can use [`$wpdb->get_results`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) for this query.